# Adding a TemplateField to a GridView at Runtime

Tags: asp.net, gridview, user-controls

I have a set of GridViews and DataSources which shared several columns and settings, so I combined them all into one `UserControl`, which I gave a `DataControlFieldCollection` to enabled me add columns to the aspx file.  Thus, I can do this:

```
<mine:PreGeneratedGridView runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="mycolumn"
            HeaderText="My Header" SortExpression="mycolumn" />
    </Columns>
</mine:PreGeneratedGridView>
```

I am using this code to move additional columns into the `GridView` that is contained in my `PreGeneratedGridView` `UserControl`:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Columns.Count; ++i)
        {
            if (IsPostBack) myGridView.Columns.RemoveAt(i);
            myGridView.Columns.Insert(i, Columns[i]);
        }
    }
```

It strikes me as a bit ugly (and probably flat out wrong, though it seems to work) to be adding the columns to the `GridView` on every page load, but when I tried putting this column-loading code into `Page_Init` it prevented columns of type `TemplateField` from running (i.e., the columns were blank, though the header was not) during a `PostBack`.

Is there a way to load my columns without using `Page_Load`/`IsPostBack` in this manner?

Comment: I don't understand why you have to remove them and reinsert them on postbacks. What happens if, on the postback, you simply do nothing with the table columns?

Comment: @Andrew: The `TemplateField` columns end up being blank, excluding the header.

Answer (score 0):

The following example should help you. It uses a class that implements ITemplate and allows you to add controls to dynamically created TemplateFields with EditItemTemplates.

[How to add a ComboBox to an asp.net unbound GridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684154/how-to-add-a-combobox-to-an-asp-net-unbound-gridview/3685097#3685097)

Comment: That does not really help me.  My issue is not about working with the `TemplateField` itself.  Rather, I have an already-working, self-contained `TemplateField` and wish to copy the entire `TemplateField` into a `GridView`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely certain what you're asking, but if your goal is to display fields in a `TemplateField` in a GridView where the GridView is bound to an anonymous type, you could write something like this, using the `Eval` method:

```
// Code to bind GridView
gv.DataSource = foo.Select( x => new {
    field1 = x.boomboom(),
    field2 = x.scramble() };
gv.DataBind;

<%-- code in your ASP.net codebehind --%>
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <%# Eval("field1").ToString() %>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <%# Eval("field12).ToString() %>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```